# Android ViewPager with android:layout_weight="1" is not shown

Tags: android

I want to display a scroll view within ViewPager and action buttons below the ViewPager. So I set `android:layout_weight="1"` to ViewPager, but it was not displayed, and only action buttons was displayed.

The layout of ViewPager is following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:text="この記事の投稿者に" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="メールで問い合わせ" />

        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="電話で問い合わせ" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The layout within ViewPager is following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:textSize="21sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/price"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:textSize="34sp"
                android:textColor="#FF0000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:textSize="21sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry, I made an easy mistake. I forgot `android:orientation="vertical"` at LinearLayout at top, and so action buttons was not displayed below the ViewPager.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using weights with Layouts you need to use a height or width, depending on the orientation, of "0dp"

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.8" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:weight="0.2">

<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:text="この記事の投稿者に" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="メールで問い合わせ" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="電話で問い合わせ" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The first LinearLayout in this code lacks the Attribute android:orientation="vertical" again! :p